# Modify Listener on Text Field

Tags: java, radio-button, swt, selection

I have added a Modify listener on text field , When I try to open the dialog it fires the Modify listener event and gives null pointer exception before the dialog is opened

Here is my code

```
 UserNameDialog dialog = new UserNameDialog(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell(), true);
    dialog.init("", userSession.hasAdminRights(), false, true, false, "");
    dialog.open();
    if (dialog.getReturnCode() == Window.CANCEL) {
        return;
    }
```

**Dialog Class**

```
public class UserNameDialog extends TitleAreaDialog {
private Text txtUsername;
@Override
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
    setMessage("Enter user information and press OK");
    setTitle("User Information");
    Composite area = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
    Composite container = new Composite(area, SWT.NONE);
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
    container.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));

    Label lblUserName = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
    lblUserName.setText("User name");

    txtUsername = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER);
    txtUsername.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));
    txtUsername.addListener(SWT.Modify, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            getButton(IDialogConstants.OK_ID).setEnabled(isValidUsername());
            // As I try to open the dialog the handler comes here and throws exception on 
            // getButton(IDialogConstants.OK_ID)
        }

    });
    if(newUser || currentUserisAdmin)
        txtUsername.setEditable(true);
    else
        txtUsername.setEditable(false);
    txtUsername.setText(name);

    new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
    new Label(container, SWT.NONE);

    return area;
}

/**
 * Create contents of the button bar.
 * @param parent
 */
@Override
protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
     okButton = createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.OK_ID, IDialogConstants.OK_LABEL, true);
     createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_ID, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_LABEL, false);
     okButton.setEnabled(false);
}

private boolean isValidUsername()
{
    String username = txtUsername.getText();
    return username != null && username.trim().length() > 0;
}
}
```

It is inside a dialog but its called before the creation of the dialog I think because okButton is null

Comment: Your code looks just fine. Are you sure the listener isn't called or maybe `enableOkButton` just isn't called because of your `if` check?

Comment: its fine but I am not able to add ModifyListener on a text field it gives me nullpointer exception

Comment: You'll have to post the code that does it then.

Comment: code added to the question

Comment: Ok and finally: Please post the stack trace and indicate the line that throws the exception.

Comment: check the edit when I try to open the dialog box it fire the listener inside the listener I am enabling and disabling ok Button Is it possible not to fire the event before the dialog is opened ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64248/discussion-between-baz-and-wearybands).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thanks to Baz for his help. I posted all the related code but I couldn't figure out why your solution is not working. What I have done and worked for me is as follows

```
 txtUsername.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            updateOKButton();
        }
    });


@Override
protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
     okButton = createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.OK_ID, IDialogConstants.OK_LABEL, true);
     createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_ID, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_LABEL, false);
     okButton.setEnabled(false);
}


private void updateOKButton() {
    if(newUser){    
        if(txtUsername.getText() == null || txtUsername.getText().isEmpty()){
            this.setMessage("Username can not be empty!");
            okButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if(txtPassword.getText().isEmpty() && txtPassword_1.getText().isEmpty()){
            this.setMessage("Passwords cannot be null!");
            okButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if (!(txtPassword.getText().equals(txtPassword_1.getText()))) {
            this.setMessage("Password do not match!");
            okButton.setEnabled(false);     
        }else {
            this.setMessage(null);
            okButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    else{
        if(txtUsername.getText() == null || txtUsername.getText().isEmpty()){
            this.setMessage("Username can not be empty!");
            okButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else {
            this.setMessage(null);
            okButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is an example with a dialog that will only enable the OK button if the username is at least one character long:

```
private Text text;

protected UsernameDialog(Shell parentShell)
{
    super(parentShell);
}

@Override
protected void configureShell(Shell newShell)
{
    super.configureShell(newShell);
    newShell.setText("Dialog");
}

@Override
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent)
{
    Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
    text = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER);
    text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.CENTER, false, false));
    text.addListener(SWT.Modify, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            getButton(IDialogConstants.OK_ID).setEnabled(isValidUsername());
        }
    });

    return container;
}

private boolean isValidUsername()
{
    String username = text.getText();
    return username != null && username.trim().length() > 0;
}

@Override
protected void okPressed()
{
    if (isValidUsername())
        super.okPressed();
    else
        System.out.println("Invalid username");
}

@Override
protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent)
{
    createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.OK_ID, IDialogConstants.OK_LABEL, true);
    createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_ID, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_LABEL, false);

    getButton(IDialogConstants.OK_ID).setEnabled(false);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new UsernameDialog(new Shell()).open();
}
```

Comment: yes the getButton(IDialogConstants.OK_ID) is null, the event is fired as I click on the button to open the dialog

Comment: @wearybands Do you also create the buttons in the `createButtonsForButtonBar` method as I posted? Please post the whole dialog class. There is surely a copy/paste issue somewhere, because the code I posted works perfectly here.

Comment: I added the createButton method as u provided still null pointer exception

Comment: When I remove the listener from the text filed I am able to open the dialog and when the listener is there it gives exception prior to opening the dialog

Comment: @wearybands As I said, you'll have to post the code of your dialog.

Comment: @wearybands Can you mark the line that throws the exception?

Comment: I added the description where the exception is thrown

Comment: @wearybands You didn't post the whole code. I made it compile and it works just fine.

Comment: @wearybands You should really have a look at how to write an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)